# Adding part of filename as column to csv files, then concatenate

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have many csv files that look like this:

```
data/0.Raw/20190401_data.csv
```

(Only the date in the middle of the filename changes)

I want to concatenate all these files together, but add the date as a new column in the data to be able to distinguish between the different files after merging.

I wrote a bash script that adds the full path and filename as a column in each file, and then merges into a master csv. However, I am having trouble getting rid of the path and the extension to only keep the date portion

The bash script

```
#! /bin/bash

mkdir data/1.merged
for i in "data/0.Raw/"*.csv; do
  awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1{sub(/\_data.csv$/, "", FILENAME) } NR>1{ $1=FILENAME }1' "$i" |
    column -t > "data/1.merged/"${i/"data/0.Raw/"/""}""
done
awk 'FNR > 1' data/1.merged/*.csv > data/1.merged/all_files

rm data/1.merged/*.csv 
mv data/1.merged/all_files data/1.merged/all_files.csv
```

using "sub" I was able to remove the "_data.csv" part, but as a result the column gets added as "data/0.Raw/20190401" - that is, I am having trouble removing both the part before the date as well as the part after the date.

I tried replacing sub with gensub to regex match everything except the 8 digits in the middle but that does not seem to work either.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do add sample of input and sample of output also in your question, thank you.

Comment: you're not adding the _"date as a new column"_ but replacing the first column with the date?

Comment: Thanks all. The solution by Fravadona below does exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process and concatenate all the files with a single `awk` call:

```bash
awk '
    FNR == 1 {
        date = FILENAME
        gsub(/.*\/|_data\.csv$/,"",date)
        next
    }
    { print date "," $0 }
' data/0.Raw/*_data.csv > all_files.csv
```

Comment: Amazing! This worked beautifully. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

> However, I am having trouble getting rid of the path and the extension
> to only keep the date portion

Then take look at [`basename`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) command

> **basename** *NAME* [*SUFFIX*]
>
> Print NAME with any leading directory components removed. If
> specified, also remove a trailing SUFFIX.

Example

```
basename 'data/0.Raw/20190401_data.csv' _data.csv
```

gives output

```
20190401
```